# Adding Raster to Weighted Overlay causes large parts of Output Raster to have NoData pixel values?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, modelbuilder, reclassify, weighted-overlay

I've been building a large suitability analysis model in ModelBuilder over the past couple of months, it has a total of 11 rasters created and put into a weighted overlay. The model runs and an acceptable output is created when I have 10/11 Rasters used in the weighted overlay, I have one raster that for some reason causes the output raster to have Nodata Pixel values for large areas.
I can't give a more detailed description without typing a pretty lengthy write up so I hope this is enough, if not I will update the post when I have a chance.
Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: What program are you using and what version? May also want to attach 1 raster that works and the one that does not

Comment: Does your raster 11 have a lot of nodata pixels? Within the model builder, are you using one of the weighted overlay tools or a map algebra expression?